# What is ctime and mtime used for in the git index?

Tags: git, git-index

When a file is added to the index for the first time the file’s create timestamp is stored in the index record's `ctime` and the file's current modified time stamp is stored in the `mtime` field.

When the file is added after a change, the `mtime` is updated with the current timestamp of the file.

When the file is checked out it does not use the `mtime` for the 
What are these timestamps used for in the world of git?

Looking at references to the index they just seem to be there. Maybe they had some future purpose that was never realized?

```
$ git ls-files --debug readme.txt
readme.txt
  ctime: 1531246924:79161700
  mtime: 1531258019:669963000
  dev: 0        ino: 0
  uid: 0        gid: 0
  size: 13      flags: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index has three names: "the index" (the one you used here), the *staging-area* (which is better in some sense as it describes its function), and the *cache*.  It's the last name that applies here.

What makes the index an index or cache, as opposed to just a staging area, is that it indexes and caches the contents of the *work-tree*.  The point of caching is to speed things up.  But caches invariably have a problem: at some point, some or all of the data *in* the cache becomes invalid.  The cache, which provides fast/short-cut access to the real, actual, correct data, no longer reflects reality.  The cache must be discarded or refilled with correct data.

Now, Git's index holds a *copy* of the file that is, or at least was at `git checkout` time, in the work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  If you have *changed* the file in some way, how is Git going to know that the cached copy is invalid?

Git's answer is to store, along with the cached copy, some of the `stat` information *about* that file, including the file's size and the two time stamps you observed.  If you modify the file in some way—even to the extent of just changing its mode, which does not touch the file's contents (so the size and mtime remain unchanged)—the ctime timestamp will be updated, and Git will know that something has changed.  Of course if you modify the contents or change the size, Git will also know.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically the index holds a *cleaned* copy of the file, ready to commit.  If you have end-of-line settings and/or smudge and/or clean filters, the cleaned copy may not actually match the work-tree copy.

---

You noted that:

> When the file is checked out it does not use the mtime for the [unfinished thought here]

I think what you have observed is one of Git's other optimizations.  If you run `git checkout <commit-specifier>` in an empty situation (e.g., the first checkout of a clone operation), Git has to completely populate the index and work-tree for the first time.  Once you have done that, though, if you now run a *different* `git checkout` to check out some *other* commit, Git can optimize the checkout:

- The index contains all the files of the current commit, as stored in the work-tree.
- The new commit you want to have checked-out has many files that are 100% identical to the current commit.
- Therefore, Git needs only to replace the *differing* files, in both the index and the work-tree.

As a result, the mtime of files that are the same between the two commits, in the work-tree, remains unchanged, because those files have not been touched at all.

This is just yet another aspect of the cache doing its caching.  However, it does play into the ability to switch branches while carrying some modifications around in your index and/or work-tree.  For details, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent details. I just tested a new repository and it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> . If you modify the file in some way—even to the extent of just changing its mode, which does not touch the file's contents (so the size and mtime remain unchanged)—the ctime timestamp will be updated, and Git will know that something has changed

Actually... not with **`git mv`**: before Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git mv`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/909d5b646e9bb49c9c242c82d68e29c451988541/Documentation/git-mv.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup> failed to refresh the cached stat information for the entry it moved.

See [commit b7f9130](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7f9130a06a9960144bb9c145e62dac792328c20) (29 Mar 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 909d5b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/909d5b646e9bb49c9c242c82d68e29c451988541), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`mv`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7f9130a06a9960144bb9c145e62dac792328c20): refresh stat info for moved entry
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Maximilian Reichel</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Update the stat info of the moved index entry in '`rename_index_entry_at()`' if the entry is up-to-date with the index.
> Internally, '[`git mv`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7f9130a06a9960144bb9c145e62dac792328c20/Documentation/git-mv.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv))</sup> uses '`rename_index_entry_at()`' to move the source index entry to the destination.
> However, it directly copies the stat info of the original cache entry, which will not reflect the 'ctime' of the file renaming operation that happened as part of the move.
>
> If a file is otherwise up-to-date with the index, that difference in 'ctime' will make the entry appear out-of-date until the next index-refreshing operation (e.g., '[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7f9130a06a9960144bb9c145e62dac792328c20/Documentation/git-status.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup>).
>
> Some commands, such as '[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7f9130a06a9960144bb9c145e62dac792328c20/Documentation/git-reset.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup>, use the cached stat information to determine whether a file is up-to-date; if this information is incorrect, the command will fail when it should pass.
> In order to ensure a moved entry is evaluated as 'up-to-date' when appropriate, refresh the destination index entry's stat info in '`git mv`' if and only if the file is up-to-date.